# Endless call of onmouseover & onmouseout after onmousedown event

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have HTML page with `span` element where `onmouseover`, `onmouseout` and `onmousedown` are setted (I can't change this page).

`onmouseover` sets class to `tt_high` which makes text underlined.

`onmouseout` removes `tt_high` class so that text is not underlined anymore.

`onmousedown` creates new div inside of `<div id="bar">` element.

This is HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .tt_high {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="foo" onmousedown="fooClicked()"
            onmouseover="highlightFoo(1)"
            onmouseout="highlightFoo(0)">Foo</span>

        <div id="bar"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var highlightFoo = function(active) {
                console.log('highlight ' + active);

                var r = document.getElementById('foo');
                if (r != null) {
                    r.className = (active) ? 'tt_high' : '';
                }
            };

            var fooClicked = function() {
                var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newDiv.innerText = 'FooBar';

                document.getElementById('bar').appendChild(newDiv);
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice that `highlightFoo` function has `console.log`. I upload [this](http://walery.bitbucket.org/misc/highlightError.html) to my bitbucket account.

Now I'd like to click this element in IE9 with Selenium:

```
public void clickFoo() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),
        DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());

    driver.get("http://walery.bitbucket.org/misc/highlightError.html");

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
    element.click();
}
```

I didn't quit WebDriver so IE is still there. Now open console (F12 -> Console) and you will see that `highlightFoo(0)` - `highlightFoo(1)` is called all the time.

Can somebody explain me what happens here and how to avoid it?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be happening to me (on IE 10, and even in IE9 mode). I see `highlight 1` when I mouse over the link and `highlight 0` when I move the mouse away. Does this happen when you click the link manually, or only when you click it with Selenium?

Comment: Only with selenium. Manually it works like expected

Comment: What is your selenium version? Also make sure your IE zoom level is 100%.

Comment: The IE driver is incredibly sensitive to the position of the actual, physical mouse cursor. In the default case, using the IE driver with native events enabled and with the "persistent hover" capability enabled, the IE driver will continue to throw mouse movement messages to the IE browser window. There are [a couple](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/06/whats-wrong-with-internet-explorer.html) of [blog posts](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html) that you should read that talk about this kind of thing.